# Moving users folder without breaking system restore?

Tags: windows-7, ssd

I'm building my dream PC but I'm having some serious issues. I've tried TWICE to get everything installed and setup using the method of creating a hard link or junction to move the Users folder to my D drive, as described [on Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5467758/move-the-users-directory-in-windows-7). The reason for this is because of using a SSD drive for the OS and program files.

Everything worked for a while, but some misbehaving programs have broken the link, or simply frozen the system. I've also discovered that using system restore with this method breaks my user profile login every single time. I can use the registry to fix this (well partially, a lot of settings still disappear), but I need a reliable PC and this doesn't cut it.

I haven't tried the unattended install method yet. Is it more reliable? Does it work with system restore? I hate to have to go through the process of installing all my files again, but if it's a better way to go about it, then it's worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a junction point for your own user folder instead of the whole users folder.

This way, you have your settings and application data migrated without affecting the OS.